# Unable to install Pandas Library using pip3

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I try to install Pandas library uisg `pip3` and get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/chaklader/PycharmProjects/OptimizingPublicTransport/producers/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-brdwlohn/pandas_7fb71e5a5c944478a4b18f60d65daa50/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-brdwlohn/pandas_7fb71e5a5c944478a4b18f60d65daa50/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-wheel-1lu27a0t
       cwd: /private/var/folders/k4/q3psbyqj0l79b8ch527mr36h0000gp/T/pip-install-brdwlohn/pandas_7fb71e5a5c944478a4b18f60d65daa50/
  Complete output (938 lines):


  /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:551:1: note: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_FromUnicode(
  ^
  /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
  #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                       ^
  14 warnings and 4 errors generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
```

Whats the issue here and how to resolve it?

Comment: ever considered miniconda/anaconda?

Comment: @LeiYang I am not very familiar with the Python ecosystem. So what I need to do to solve the issue? If you can write an answer, this will be very helpful.

Comment: added an answer.

Comment: I installed it inside a virtual environment and the errors come from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're using a too high python version, see similar issues [1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32045) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370149/problems-installing-pandas-and-yfinance-with-python-3-9-on-my-mac).

You can try python 3.6. You should always upgrade `pip` before installing packages.

And as you can see in the pip install log, it tries to compile from some C/C++ source, requiring the build tools which are sometimes unavailable.

So I suggest you use [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/), from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)):

> Anaconda is a distribution of the Python and R programming languages
> for scientific computing (data science, machine learning applications,
> large-scale data processing, predictive analytics, etc.), that aims to
> simplify package management and deployment.